# Angular2 HttpClient get requests that respond with application/javascript are parsed as JSON but I want them to be `eval`'d

Tags: javascript, angular, http

The tl;dr of my question: Is there a way to setup Angular's HttpClient to have this same behavior as it does in the jQuery and CGI example? Is there a way of using the Angular HttpClient to not interpret the response as JSON, but instead just `eval(response_data)`?

When running `ng serve` and making a request in the application using `HttpClient#get`, like this...

```
return this.httpClient.get('/assets/values.json')
return this.httpClient.get('/assets/values.js')
```

... the Angular development web server returns a response with an appropriate `Content-Type` header, of which the value for the above get requests are, respectively:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: application/javascript
```

If I put JavaScript in the **values.js** file, I get a syntax error, "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" -- which to me is an obvious indication that the application/javascript is not being executed in the browser. It's being interpreted through the automatic execution of the `JSON.parse` function. The file should not be interpreted as JSON, and this is not the behavior I want.

The behavior that I want is to execute the JavaScript response, similar to what happens when a CGI server response is returned:

```
Content-Type: text/javascript

x=1;
```

If I run a web app that calls `jQuery.get('/values.js')`, and a CGI backend script returns the above response, then `x` has the value `1` in my browser's window (the JavaScript global) object. This is the (somewhat unclear behavior) of jQuery, but I am guessing it has to do with using the Content-Type header. Seemingly, `jQuery#ajax` is called with a `dataType: "script"` property on the options.

**EDIT:** Before you ask "why am I doing it like this? Try doing this instead..." The reason I'm using assets like this is to create an environment exactly like that which I am building this app for. The GUI app is going to run in an environment with a CGI backend, and the API Response Format described in the backend is specified. I cannot change it. I would like to design my frontend app using mock behavior so that I don't have to deploy the app every time I want to test it. The frontend application being developed using `ng serve` is an ideal environment because of its auto-refreshing developer experience, and to make it even more useful for me (I think) I want this behavior.

Comment: if its an asset why are not creating a ts file? and then simply import that json

Comment: i really appreciate what you asked ,if i had an answer i will definetly answer that, but i am sorry i can't help you, FYI i din't cast a vote, and yeah i understand your question

Comment: It’s unclear what you want. Suppose you could do a get that returns js - what would you like to do with that js?

Comment: Maybe I’m still a bit unclear about this (my shortcoming). So are you open to alternatives? When calling this you are in Angular scope, so you can’t compare this with jQuery behaviour. What you want (if I understand you correctly) is fairly easily done by simply (dynamically) injecting a script tag in the head and setting the src to your js file. This should add the contents to window scope. Another option is to fetch it has text and then eval the text on window I guess?

Comment: Just also add an id to the script tag, check if it exists first and if so, replace it. I hope it works out for you :-)

Comment: I'll update the question with the new discovery of the jQuery documentation that I found. Also, I have the answer to the question after reading the HttpClient documentation on angular.io/docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different HttpClient#get configuration object, so that Angular does not interpret the response as JSON and it will not return the return value of `JSON.parse` when it's configured as below:

```
const options = {
  observe: 'body' as const,
  responseType: 'text' as const,
};
return this.httpClient.get('/assets/values.js', options)
```

When the HttpClient#get returns, the value will be an Observable with the response body as a parameter of the data returned.

You can subscribe to the Observable and call eval like this `.subscribe(data => eval(data))` to get the same behavior as jQuery.